# WP-CLI Get Site ID from its url

Tags: wp-cli

I know I can get a site list with wp site list --path="$pathtowordpress"

What I want to do though is get one site's ID by knowing only it's url.

Does anyone know if this is possible ?

Tnaks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `--url` isn't working to filter the `wp site list` output.

So instead one could try:

```
wp site list | awk '{ if( $2 == SITE_URL_STRING ) print $1; }'
```

where we use the `awk` trick from [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/31755/31912), to filter the `url` column and display the `blog_id` column.

Here we must replace `SITE_URL_STRING` with e.g. `"https://blog.example.com/site9/"`.

*Update:* Here's a bash example to find the exact site url string:

```
#!/bin/bash
site_url="https://blog.example.com/site9/"
wp site list | awk -v site_url=$site_url '{ if( $2 == site_url ) print $1; }'
```

where we use the `-v` option to pass a shell variable to awk. Got that idea from  [here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-appleosx-bsd-bash-passing-variables-to-awk/).

Comment: EXCELLENT ! - That solved the problem.  I adjusted that by just a bit to remove the == requirement as I wanted to rule out http vs https requirements.  This is the final string:   
--allow-root | awk '{ if( index($2,"mydomain.com") != 0 ) print $1; }'
OR
--allow-root | awk '{ if( index($2,"blog.example.com/site9") != 0 ) print $1; 
}'
Depending on how you are structuring your URL's in wordpress

Comment: Glad to hear it helped. Thanks for sharing your workaround. There could also be other workarounds, like using `wp db query ...`. but I think it's not recommended in general to run wp-cli as `root` with `--allow-root`. Another thing that comes to mind is to watch out for cases like mydomain.com and thisismydomain.com when using index/substring matches.

Comment: I'm using this in a bash file script ie;
--------------- returns nothing with $wpurl ie; --------------------
wp site list --path="$pathtowordpress" --allow-root --color | awk '{ if(  index($2,"$wpurl") != 0  ) print $1; }'
----------------------------
Have tried inserting variable with single quotes, double quotes and ".$wpurl." but all return empty so I'm sure it's not processing that variable correctly.----- When  I try remove quotes entirely, it just errors out on the period of the .com section.

.... Any advice ?

Comment: I updated the answer with an example. Hope it works for you.

Comment: Worked like a charm!  I noticed you went in a different direction than index.  Thank you. Resolved again ;-)

Comment: great, there's also the [regular expression comparison](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/gawk/gawk_26.html) `~` instead of `==` if you need to skip the scheme.